# How to use listview in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

My data format is like this
`{"foo1":"bar1","foo2":["bar2","bar3","bar4"]}
,{"foo1":"bar5","foo2":["bar6","bar7","bar8"]}`

I'am using recyclerview for root object and want to use foo3 as listview in recyclerview. Is it possible and how?

Example of recyclerview list item layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFoo1Value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvFoo2Values"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ViewHolder is like this

```
public class FooViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public final View mView;
public final TextView tvFoo1Value;
public final ListView lvFoo2Values;

public ChallengeViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    mView = view;
    this.tvFoo1Value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFoo1Value);
    this.lvFoo2Values = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvFoo2Values);
}}
```

Also ViewAdapter is

```
public class FooRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FooViewHolder> {
..
private View view;

  @Override
public FooViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context ctx = parent.getContext();
    view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
            .inflate(R.layout.foo_list_item, parent, false);

    return new FooViewHolder(view);
}
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FooViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String[] foo2Arr = //comes from service

    Context ctx = view.getContext(); //?? possible error here i think

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,foo2Arr);
    holder.lvFoo2Values.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
..
}
```

Comment: try this [link](http://androhub.com/android-recyclerview/).

Comment: Thanks but on the link there is nothing new for me, i just looking ways for displaying an array inside recyclerview

Comment: You should not use a scrollable view inside another scrollable view.

Comment: @HasanAliKaraca : Could you implement above question with listview under recyclerview? Please post any hint if you have, as I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to convert that JSON into a java object. You could use any library for this (GSON, Jackson, etc.)

Your class will probably look like this

```
public class TheJSON {
    public String foo1;
    public ArrayList<String> foo2;
}
```

Once you get the JSON represented in Java objects, then use multiple view types in your `RecyclerView` adapter

```
public class TheAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<TheJSON> json_collection;
    private ArrayList<String> the_strings;
    private ArrayList<int> the_view_types;

    public TheAdapter(ArrayList<TheJSON> json_collection) {
        this.json_collection = json_collection;

        for (int i = 0; i < json_collection; i++) {
            the_string.add(json_collection.get(i).foo1);
            the_view_types.add(1);
            for (int j = 0; j < json_collection.get(i).foo2.size(); j++) {
                the_string.add(json_collection.get(i).foo2.get(j));
                the_view_types.add(2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case 1:
                return new Foo1ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.foo1_layout, parent, false));

            case 2:
                return new Foo2ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.foo2_layout, parent, false));

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (the_view_types.get(position)) {
            case 1:
                Foo1ViewHolder foo1ViewHolder = (Foo1ViewHolder) holder;
                foo1ViewHolder.setText(the_strings.get(position));
                break;

            case 2:
                Foo2ViewHolder foo2ViewHolder = (Foo2ViewHolder) holder;
                foo2ViewHolder.setText(the_strings.get(position));
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return the_strings.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return the_view_types.get(position);
    }

    public class Foo1ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvFoo1Value;

        public Foo1ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFoo1Value = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFoo1Value);
        }

        public setText(String text) {
            tvFoo1Value.setText(text);
        }
    }

    public class Foo2ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvFoo2Value;

        public Foo2ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFoo2Value = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFoo2Value);
        }

        public setText(String text) {
            tvFoo2Value.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to show in a textview, i want to show in a listview because i will use some styling in it. Sorry this is not i asked.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Having a scrollable view inside another scrollable view is generally not recommended as it may cause problems with gesture detection. Have you tried flattening the array and use multiple layout in the RecyclerView?

Comment: Hmm so what is the best way to show an array in a recyclerview? I am trying to show with linearlayout, adding dynamic views

Comment: That's what I usually do. Adding dynamic views approach are also ok but you'll need to be more careful with your memory usage. Inflating XMLs over and over again consumes a lot of memory over time. Let me edit my answer to fit your scenario using view types approach